Homeomorphism from a quotient space of the upper half plane to the plane
Consider the closed upper half plane,
$$\mathbb H^2:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:y\geq 0\},$$
and an equivalence relation given by,
$(x,y)\sim (x',y')$ $\iff$ $(x,y)=(x',y')$ or $y=0=y'$ and $x'=-x$ (ie we identify the anti-podal points on $\mathbb R\times \{0\}\subset \mathbb H^2$).
I think the quotient space $\mathbb H^2/\sim$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$. This is my “geometric intution”: because we are attaching the anti-podal points on $y=0$, the two spaces in the picture below are the “same thing”. The latter is the open ball and hence homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$. I know an explicit homeomorphism from the ball to the plane, but how do I make the intuition (if at all it is correct) that the two spaces in the picture are homeomorphic? That is, how do I find an explicit homeomorphism?


Indeed, I have made the change now :)

It is correct. First, identify $\mathbb{R}^2 \cong \mathbb{C}$. The group $\mathbb{Z}_2$ acts on $\mathbb{C}$ by $z \mapsto -z$. Then
$$\Phi: \mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{C}, \ z\mapsto z^2$$
is a homeomorphism since $\Phi$ is well-defined, bijective, continuous by universal property of quotient topology and $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}, \ z \mapsto z^2$ is open (non-constant and holomorphic).
Further $$\Psi: \mathbb{H}^2/\sim \to \mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}_2, \ [z] \mapsto [z]$$ is homeomorphism since it is bijective and continuous by the universal property of quotient topology and
$$\mathbb{H}^2 \to \mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}_2, \ z \mapsto [z]$$
is a quotient map since it is closed, surjective and continuous ($\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}_2, \ z \mapsto [z]$ is a closed quotient map since $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a finite group and $\mathbb{H}^2\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is closed). Thus
$$\Phi\circ \Psi: \mathbb{H}^2/\sim \to \mathbb{C}, \ [z] \mapsto z^2$$ is a homeomorphism.

Thank you, makes sense :)
